# AWS Redshift COPY from S3

Tags: hive, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy Hive created SEQUENCE files from S3 to Redshift.  What do I need to add as an "OPTION" to have Redshift properly recognize the filetype?  Thanks!

Comment: You should store the Hive output in one of the compression standards of Redshift COPY command; gz or lzo.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format of the output file from Hive. For compression type, redshift supports **GZIP** or **LZOP**, and for file type, redshift supports flat file, **csv** or **json**, you may also use **DELIMITER** to specify the column delimiter. And you may also need to use **DATEFORMAT/TIMEFORMAT** to specify the date/time format used in the output file.

Not sure if this answers your question.